# Manipular items de activity desde Fragment

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Como puedo manipular los items de la Toolbar del Navigation Drawer desde un fragment que se encuentra dentro de la activity del Drawer, para que muestre y oculte los iconos?? Trabajo en Android con java.

Comment: Wayner, te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y modifiques tu pregunta. Incluye que has investigado e intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: ¿ A que te refieres @Wayner ? La sugerencia de Marcos es importante para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y no sea cerrada. Veo que incluso no has leído el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.